# MultiCell results in black color

Tags: php, fpdf

here is my code for the multicell part

```
$pdf->MultiCell(30,10,rtrim(chunk_split($row['project_name'],30,"-\n"),"- \n"),1,0,'C');
```

but it shows black cells here

[image]

Comment: do you have any FillColor above it? I also had the same thing but all I do is check my entire code and the color filling is gone

Answer (score 1):

The definition which you have provided has an extra variable which is actually causing the issue. Try removing the '0' from the definition towards the end.

```
$pdf->MultiCell(30,10,rtrim(chunk_split($row['project_name'],30,"-\n"),"- \n"),1,'C');
                                                                                ^
```